# Python Flask - receive image as post

Tags: python, post, flask

I'm having trouble receiving an image from a form on my flask python server.

Here's the code of the html form:

```
<form action="http://localhost:85/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="myImage" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here's the code of the server

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return("Welcome!")

@app.route('/upload')
def upload():
    try:
        # check if the post request has the file part
        file = request.files['myImage']
        return("Image uploaded")
        print("Image uploaded")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error occurred")
        print(err)
        return("Error, image not received.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=85)
```

Here's the output of the console when I submit the form:

```
"POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Essentially, just shows that site can't be reached. When I go to the url without submitting image the page works normally.
I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method type (POST) is missing in your route. So it's giving 405, which is `method not allowed`.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#routing

Web applications use different HTTP methods when accessing URLs. You should familiarize yourself with the HTTP methods as you work with Flask. By default, a route only answers to GET requests. You can use the method's argument of the route() decorator to handle different HTTP methods.